# Start jquery script after whole page has loaded?

Tags: jquery

How do I prevent my jQuery script from running until the whole page is loaded? (Including images .. ).

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Instead of `$(document).ready(/* ... */);` you can use:

```
$(window).load(
    function() {

});
```

Or you could just put a `script` block at the bottom of the page, so by the time the scripts are reached the rest of the DOM's loaded already.

Comment: but this doesn't mean every image has been loaded.
just the dom.

Comment: In general, it is advantageous to put your scripts at the bottom if you don't need them to execute until after the page has loaded.  By doing this browser doesn't need to interpret the JavaScript earlier and it lets the rest of the page load faster

Comment: @Sven, putting scripts at the bottom of the page *increases* the chance of the page being ready. There's no reason you can't use both techniques at the same time. Personally I always default to using `$(document).ready(/*...*/);` for whatever reason, and putting it in the `head` just because...well. Habit, I think. Though if I'm working on anything involving images in the scripts *then* I'll put a `$(window).load(/*...*/)` at the bottom instead. And marvel that I don't do that way *every* time... =/

Comment: Yeah, so far as I've ever been able to tell that's precisely what `$(window).load(/*...*/)` **does**: (reference for the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) at api.jquery.com), the example near the bottom of the page states: [`$(window).load()`] "[runs] a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics."

Comment: @Sven: no worries, it's always a pleasure; Was I able to help solve your problem?